# Can any one give me query which one is execute in Oracle 10G

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have given both query.the first query is giving proper output(I am using sqlserver).
and second query i want to execute in Oracle but it is not working.please give me correct query which one i can use in oracle.

**SqlServer**:

```
select * 
from branch a left outer join course b on a.courseid=b.courseid 
where b.courseid is NULL
```

**Oracle**:

```
select * 
from branch a, course b 
where a.courseid= b.courseid(+)
```

in oracle this clause where b.courseid is NULL is not working.

Comment: sonar,plz tell me this query is executing but it is not giving output.when i executing first query then i get which record i want to delete.

Answer (score 3):

Your tag says you are using Oracle 10g.  Oracle has supported [the ANSI join syntax since 9i](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2080416).  Consequently, the query you run in SQL Server should also work in your Oracle environment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd use the same left outer join syntax in Oracle as well rather than their older, proprietary (+) syntax.  Oracle makes the same recommendation in their documentation.  There are a number of restrictions on this syntax which do not apply to the standard ansi syntax.

If you were determined to use the Oracle join operator I'm not 100% sure but I think you'd need to do something like:

```
select *
from branch a, course b
where a.courseid = b.courseid(+)
and b.courseid(+) is null;
```

It's been a long time since I've bothered with the Oracle join operator.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Oracle query is:

```
select *
from branch a, course b
where a.courseid= b.courseid(+) and
      b.courseid is null
```

Then I think that should be equivalent to the SQL Server query.  Are you sure your data is the same in both databases?